# Единственное или множественное число после перечисления вариантов

Tags: грамотная-речь, морфология, число

Я пишу программу, в одном из блоков пользователю необходимо ввести текст.
Для ввода доступны либо русские, либо английские символы. Если пользователь вводит какие-то иные символы, то он должен увидеть оповещение об этом.

Я вывожу оповещение: "Недоступное значение! Используйте буквы английского и/или русского алфавита".

Собственно, вопрос: последнее слово я должен использовать в единственном или во множественном числе?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: ... what about ".......... Используйте буквы латинского и русского алфавита"?

Comment: @Anonym Алфавит английского языка основан на латинском алфавите (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82). IMHO: Оба термина корректны, если говорить о буквах только, но есть еще понятие "символы алфавита", и я не уверен, что "символы латинского алфавита" = "символы английского алфавита".

Comment: Согласна с Вами, но тогда не понимаю что имеет в виду автор вопроса... "английские символы"? он реферирует к "§$%&/()=?
я имею тоже эти "английские символы" на своей испанской тастатуре...

Comment: @Anonym В мире компьютеров, говоря об английских/русских символах (символах английского/русского алфавита), имеют в виду
набор символов (character set), соответствующий выбраномy локалю (locale). Tакой набoр включает буквы, цифры и другие символы (например, !@#$%^&*). При этом некоторые символы входят во многие наборы. Нет ничего странного в том, что "§$%&/()=? входят как в английский, так и в испанский набор.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал что-то такое:

Вы ввели неразрешенный символ. Используйте **только** буквы английского и русского алфавитов.

Впрочем, остаются вопросы. Неужели и цифры, и знаки препинания запрещены?

Если разрешены, то нужно говорить не о буквах, а о символах:

**Вы ввели неразрешенный символ. Используйте только символы английского и русского алфавитов.**

Comment: Если мы выбираем союз И, то - алфавитОВ! Если ИЛИ - алфавитА.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Мне кажется здесь оба варианта допустимы (и мн. и ед. ч.). Возможно, мн.ч. лучше. Я исправил.

Comment: Про число мне старенький педагог вот тут отвечает (интересное!): http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1701273-mezhdu-vtorym-i-tretim-etazhom-ili-etazhami.html

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно

> Используйте буквы английского и/или русского алфавита -

две раскладки зараз никак не получится использовать.

Значит, оставляем только "или".

А если осталось только "или", то предлагается выбор 
меж тем или иным алфавитом (ед. ч.).

Comment: Вполне можно смешать несколько алфавитов. For exmaple: english и русский.

Comment: Но у автора вопроса: *Для ввода доступны либо русские, либо английские символы.* Я же пишу не "вообще", я на вопрос отвечаю.

Comment: Автор притиворечит самому себе. С одной стороны либо-либо, с другой и/или. Поэтому мы с вами понимаем его по-разному.

Comment: Думаю, автор ошибся с *и/или* - из контекста ясно, что требуется *или*.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, не "недоступное", а "недопустимое". Во-вторых, в единственном числе.